# jQuery + PHP how to make autocomple like google

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

When you write somthing on Google, it will keep what you wrote and add
gray text as option to complete.

For Example:

[Black]Goo[/black][gray]le[/gray]
( The Black is what you wrote, and gray is possibility to autocomplete )

I tried to do that and success, but it was very slowly even though I use localhost.
So I'm asking for the best way to do this thing.

- The list of autocomplete should to be in array such like this:

  Array (
      "google", "yahoo", "stackoverflow" ...
  )

Comment: How are you storing your auto-complete dictionary, and how are you doing the lookup?

Comment: Post your code so we can see what you're doing...

Comment: start out from the assumption that I know the world that I want to complete, I'm trying to do the jquery thing.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using jQuery, maybe consider using jQueryUI to handle autocomplete for you. You provide it the url to your PHP page which should just return a json encoded string of results based on $_GET['term'] that jQueryUI will send your url.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: The autocomplete that I want should to appears in the input himself and not in the bottom of him.

Answer (score 0):

You can pre-load the list for all possible combinations of the next 2-3 characters into javascript array, and pick from it while you update the list in the background with new characters.